# Nuances between "salement / méchamment / sacrément"

Tags: sens

I just said in conversation:

> Tu as **salement** morflé sur ce coup-là, dis donc.

... but  I wonder how the following two compare?

> Tu as **méchamment** morflé sur ce coup-là, dis donc.
>
> Tu as **sacrément** morflé sur ce coup-là, dis donc.

Answer (score 1):

***Salement*** and ***méchamment*** are synonymous here and belonging to the same familiar register while ***sacrément*** is more formal and less used nowadays, just like ***dis donc*** too.

A trend in colloquial French is to use this form:

> *T'as morflé **grave** sur ç'coup là, (<expletive>) !*

Note that this might only apply to France.

Comment: I usually use "grave" with "déchirer grave", but is there an *age limit* for this particular usage of "grave"?

Comment: Not particular limit, the expression is becoming mainstream. Younger people start saying *T'as grave morflé* instead.

Comment: My own private corpus of teenagers also uses *grave* alone as a positive answer, like "et comment !" or "à fond!". Ex: "C'était bien, ta soirée ? - Grave ! "

Comment: I think it would sound out of place if used by an elderly person. Otherwise it's fine, provided you keep it to an informal context. =)